# comparación distinto que no funciona en procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado, bueno tengo bueno todo, hace lo que espero de el, pero en una linea especifica no me hace la comparación al momento que sea diferente (!=) pero al hacer un igual (=) me lo toma sin problemas, el codigo el el siguiente:

```js
CREATE DEFINER=`biciRoot`@`%` PROCEDURE `baiky`.`insertcategorias`(IN nombreCat VARCHAR(50),
                   IN fuenteCat INT,
                   IN descargableCat INT,
                   IN habilitadoCat INT,
                   IN urlCat VARCHAR(50)
                   )
BEGIN
  set @idResultCategoria = (SELECT categoria_id  FROM categorias WHERE categoria_nombre = nombreCat);
  set @idResultUrl = (SELECT link_url  FROM links WHERE link_url = urlCat);
 
 
  IF  @idResultCategoria IS NULL THEN 
   insert into categorias (categoria_nombre, categoria_fechaInsert, categoria_habilitado) 
    VALUES (nombreCat, NOW(), habilitadoCat);
   
    set @idResultCategoria = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
   
   insert into links (link_url, link_descargable,link_fechaInsert,link_fechaUpdate,categoria_id,fuente_id) 
    VALUES (urlCat, descargableCat, NOW(),NULL,@idResultCategoria,fuenteCat);
  
   ELSE
   set @idResultlink = (SELECT link_id  FROM links WHERE link_url = urlCat);
      //esta es la linea con problemas, nesecito que me realice el update cuando son diferentes y no cuando sean iguales
      // uso la siguiente linea para hacer la comparacion y ver si son diferentes, pero no me realiza el update, pero con el = si me lo hace, trate con <> pero aun asi no me realiza comparacion               IF @idResultUrl != urlCat THEN
    IF @idResultUrl = urlCat THEN 
     UPDATE links
     SET 
      link_url = urlCat,
      link_fechaUpdate = NOW()
      WHERE
      link_id = @idResultlink;
     
    END IF;

  END IF;
END
```

Comment: prueba con el operador **<>**

Comment: ya probé, tampoco me funciona

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6494f615d156044b81861436bf262ad). ¿Puede darnos algunos datos de ejemplo?, ¿qué valores tienen la variable definida por el usuario `@idResultUrl` así como el parámetro `urlCat` cuando el operador `!=` teóricamente no funciona?.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `STRCMP(variableA,variableB)` para comparar. Devuelve `0` si son **iguales**, si no devuelve `1`.
O sea que te quedar así:

```
//que actualice cuando sean distintos
IF STRCMP(@idResultUrl,urlCat) =1 THEN
```